# Copy-Paste Range from Min to Max

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste

It might be a simple question but after hours of trying about to give up...

I want the macro to find the range from a minimum to a maximum. This range should be copied and pasted to some kind of a "summary sheet".

I was able to make the macro find the min and the max and I also got a copy-paste instruction that works.

Could somebody please help me to combine these instructions into one?

Here is my macro as far as I came:

```
Sub Enter_Formula()

    Dim blatt
    Dim sheetName As String
    For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
        Sheets(i).Select
        Range("=Min(A59:A86):=Max(A:A)").Copy Range("C1")
    Next

End Sub
```

Thank you!!

Comment: I'm lost. What do you mean by `I want the macro to find the range from a minimum to a maximum`?

Comment: @L42 I need the macro to find the minimum inside a range (e.g. A59:A86) and the maximum of the whole column A. Then it should copy (starting at the found minimum ending at the found maximum) and paste the found range into a summarysheet - was that more understandable?

Comment: So if the maximum value in column A is in cell A4, and the minimum value (within A59:A86) is in cell A62, you want to copy A4:A62 to C1:59 - is that correct?  And do you want the next sheet's values to then be copied starting at C60, or write over the values starting at C1 again?  And do you want to copy formulas and formats, or just values?

Comment: The maximum value of column A will in this case always be positioned after the minimum. I just figuered out that it´d be great if I could not only copy the values from column A then but also the whole row of every data point inside the defined range (min to max). So maybe something in the direction of one summary sheet per sheet the macro runs over?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd go as follows:

```
Sub Enter_Formula()
    Dim sht As Worksheet, summarySht As Worksheet

    Set summarySht = Worksheets("Summary") '<--| change "Summary" to your actual "Summary" sheet name

    For Each sht In Worksheets
       If sht.Name <> summarySht.Name Then
            With sht.Range("A59:A86")
                .Parent.Range(.Find(what:=WorksheetFunction.Min(.Cells), lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues), .EntireColumn.Find(what:=WorksheetFunction.Max(.EntireColumn), lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues)).Copy summarySht.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(, 1)
            End With
       End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Wouldn't `WorksheetFunction.Max(.Cells)` need to be `WorksheetFunction.Max(sht.Columns(1))`?  From the question it appears to be the range from the minimum in A59:A86 to the maximum in the whole column.

Comment: @YowE3K Yeah youre right, I meant maximum of the whole column and minimum of the range A59:A86

Comment: @user7761353,  edited to extend the range to the cell with the maximum value on entire column A. If it solves your question thne please mark answer as accepted. thank you!

Comment: @user3598756 yet the macro just copies the whole column A and pastes it into the summary sheet. What It does not just copy the range from the found minimum to the found maximum.

Comment: P.S. the summary sheet should show all the ranges (from found min to found max) of every sheet next to each other... that does not work neither yet

Comment: _"next to each other"_: that you're saying right now. _"that does not work neither yet"_: seems like there's something else not working, what is it?. With a complete _picture_ I can try and edit my answer. thank you!

Comment: see edit to have each range from sheets pasted into _next_ column of summary sheet

Comment: @user3598756 the summary sheet works with your edit. Thank you very much you helped me a lot!!

Comment: you are welcome. I'd appreciate you could accept the answer by clicking on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Might be a bit faster to evaluate the expression directly (tested):

```
Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In Worksheets
    ws.Range("Index(A59:A86,Match(Min(A59:A86),A59:A86,0)):Index(A:A,Match(Max(A:A),A:A,0))").Copy ws.Range("C1")
Next
```